# Angular 5 service failing to pass unit tests with (NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, angular5

I keep getting the following errors when running unit tests

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ApiService -> HttpClient]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ApiService -> HttpClient]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  url = './assets/data.json';

  get() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

**api.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';

describe('ApiService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        ApiService,
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should get users', inject([HttpTestingController, ApiService],
      (httpMock: HttpTestingController, apiService: ApiService) => {
        expect(apiService).toBeTruthy();
      }
    )
  );
});
```

I don't understand what is going wrong as I have included HttpClient into api.service.ts, the service works in the browser.

This is directly called in a component called MapComponent, and that is called inside HomeComponent.

```
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Mac OS X 10.13.3) HomeComponent expect opened to be false FAILED
    Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ApiService -> HttpClient]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ApiService -> HttpClient]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

Answer (score 65):

The reason for `"NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!"` are unresolved dependencies. In this case the lack of a `HttpClientModule`.

In your .service.spec.ts file add

```
  imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
    ],
```

You might notice that I wrote **`HttpClientTestingModule`** instead of `HttpClientModule`. The reason is that we don't want to send actual http requests, but rather use a Mock API of the test framework.

Comment: Don't forget to make the same change in app.module.ts as well (Angular 5 context).

Comment: but he has imported the HttpClientTestingModule in his .service.spec.ts, as it is shown above?

Comment: @Marius you also need to add it to imports array of TestBed configuration object as shown in the answer

Comment: Hi JP07, I just want to ask that if I'm injecting `private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef` in constructor, then is it required to mock this service in spec file also. I'm asking this because I'm new to angular. I don't know. Please help.

Answer (score 16):

simply add it like this,

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem! Btw I do not like the angular way of testing because it is very shady - the fact that this is the 5-th stackoverflow topic for the problem I have tells me it is very complex to write these test the right way. I don't know if I just need to learn more about the angular test or other people are frustrated because their testing mechanism is blaah.

Answer (score 14):

Try wrapping your `inject` in an `async`, like below:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

describe('ApiService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      ...
    });    

  it(`should create`, async(inject([HttpTestingController, ApiService],
    (httpClient: HttpTestingController, apiService: ApiService) => {
      expect(apiService).toBeTruthy();
  })));

});
```

Don't forget to import `async` from `@angular/core/testing`.

I have had good success with this. It's the only different from your unit tests and mine where I use `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Comment: What is the idea behind that?

Comment: @Amadán This may answer your question: https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-async

Comment: @Dan See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809262/failing-test-after-adding-service-with-httpclient/51809727#51809727) for a more complete answer to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have imports `HttpClientModule and HttpClientTestingModule` modules which resoved my issues.

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

  imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
```

Comment: where did you import these files?

Comment: You need to import these files in the component spec.